# Getting a page via LWP::UserAgent with proxy. Also fails with wget and curl. Browser works fine

Tags: perl, proxy, lwp

I had a very simply script (see sample) downloading my report from our internal server  for months. Then IT made some changes to the infrastructure, and ever since I can not get this script working any more.

I can fetch the file using Chrome or Internet Explorer, but not with Perl or Python. Even wget and curl fail.

- If I provide incorrect proxy credential then I rightfully get `407 Proxy Authentication`.
- If I set the timeout to 60 seconds then I get `500 read timeout`.
- If I set the timeout to 90 seconds, I get `503 Service Unavailable`. Curl returns `network timeout`.

The IT department insist that if a browser works then there is no problem. Am I missing something else?

### Perl sample

```
require LWP::UserAgent;

my $url =  "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/StandardReport.aspx?itemid=yyyy&date=dd-mm-yyyy&adjustments&xml=1";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(90);
$ua->proxy(['http', 'ftp'], 'http://my_user:my_password@proxy_uri:8080');

my $response = $ua->get($url);
 
if ( $response->is_success ) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

Comment: Look at the credentials method in LWP

Comment: $ua->credentials(
  'uri:80',
  'web_server_usage_reports',
  '_login' => '_pass'
); tried - no luck

Comment: What URL are you using in Chrome? Is it the same as `$url` in your Perl code? Please show the Chrome proxy configuration. I suggest you show the IT department a wget command line that doesn't work for you. They are likely to be able to spot the problem

Comment: url in Chrome is exactly the same as in Perl, curl, wget. IT would not co-operate as they don’t want to get involved in something which is not a standard setup.  proxy setting in Chrome/IE is http://autoproxy.xxx.xxx.xxx/yyy.pac but in Perl I am using proxy url given to me by IT

Comment: Have you tried to hide/fake browser info? `$ua->agent('');`  [A wild guess/try]

Comment: $ua->agent(''); - still same problem..